# Creating a script to retrieve image uploaded to a Google Cloud bucket

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform

I have set up a Cloud Storage bucket, a cloud Pub/Sub topic, and a subscription to create a notification when a file is uploaded to the bucket.

I would like to create a script on a server that subscribes to the message when a new image is uploaded to the bucket, and downloads the image locally to the server. I am not sure how to go about this -- can anyone give me resources or pointers in the right direction?

Comment: Please show us how your script looks so far so that we can see how we can help you.

Comment: I'm not sure where to get started. 

I have used `gsutil mb gs://image_upload_bucket` to create a new bucket and

```gsutil notification create -t uploaded_images -f json -e OBJECT_FINALIZE gs://image_upload_bucket``` to write the pub/sub topic to the bucket

i have also created a subscription using
`gcloud beta pubsub subscriptions create analyze_image --topic=uploaded_images` to see the notifications. what i want to do is retrieve the image uploaded to the bucket, and download it locally, is this possible?

Comment: command to get retrieved image is gsutil cp gs://bucketname/imagefilename .  Please specify folder name instead of "."

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/downloading-objects

Comment: I figured out my problem. Will post below. Was a combination of Inder's link + https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/blob/master/storage/cloud-client/notification_polling.py

Answer (score 0):

The answer was a combination of a few things. The gist of what I had to do can be found in these methods:

```
from google.cloud import pubsub_v1, storage

def retrieve_image(message):

    attributes = message.attributes

    bucket_id = attributes['bucketId']
    source_blob_name = attributes['objectId']
    destination_file_name = 'images/' + source_blob_name

    download_blob(bucket_id, source_blob_name, destination_file_name)

def download_blob(bucket_name, source_blob_name, destination_file_name):
    """Downloads a blob from the bucket."""
    storage_client = storage.Client()
    bucket = storage_client.get_bucket(bucket_name)
    blob = bucket.blob(source_blob_name)

    blob.download_to_filename(destination_file_name)

    print('Blob {} downloaded to {}.'.format(
        source_blob_name,
        destination_file_name))

def poll_notifications(project, subscription_name):
    """Polls a Cloud Pub/Sub subscription for new GCS events for display."""
    # [BEGIN poll_notifications]
    subscriber = pubsub_v1.SubscriberClient()
    subscription_path = subscriber.subscription_path(
        project, subscription_name)

    def callback(message):
        print('Received message:\n{}'.format(summarize(message)))
        retrieve_image(message)
        # run_openpose(message)
        message.ack()

    subscriber.subscribe(subscription_path, callback=callback)

    # The subscriber is non-blocking, so we must keep the main thread from
    # exiting to allow it to process messages in the background.
    print('Listening for messages on {}'.format(subscription_path))
    while True:
        time.sleep(60)
    # [END poll_notifications]
```